# how to retrieve records in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am having a record with some values in db(MySQL) + eclipselink. I am using following code to retrieve that record

```
EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEntityManager();
TypedQuery<User> query =  em.createQuery("select u from User u where u.email='tomj@abc.com'", User.class);
List<User> results = query.getResultList();
for(User u:results){
  System.out.println(u.getEmail());
}
```

the record in my sample db has a row with email 'tomj@abc.com'. Still when I print the list I get blank / empty list printed. I think I am going wrong somewhere. Can anyone tell me what is the mistake?

PS: I also tried to use getSingleResult which throws an exception.

Comment: I think your query might have errors, have you tried running your query through something other than your java code to see if it returns the correct record?

Comment: I think the query should look something like: `"select * from User where User.email='tomj@abc.com'"`

Comment: If I use normal sql it returns me proper records I am trying JPA for the first time.

User.email throws exception

Comment: could you please share the exception?

Comment: The JPQL is correct (assuming email is a String field), there is no * in JPQL. But then the poster should present what SQL was actually sent to the DB (in the log) ... and the exception of course

Comment: @user1079065 Are you sure that the content of the column is _exactly_ `tomj@abc.com`, no whitespace at the beginning or end, no invisible characters, and all letters written in lower case? Sometimes it helps to copy the value from the database straight into the Java editor.

Comment: Please, make sure to also show us the User entity.

Comment: Have you tried the parameter approach? `em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email", User.class).setParameter("email", "tomj@abc.com");` The JPQL string looks fine to me. What's the exception saying?

Comment: I suppose that @TobiasLiefke is right... If you get a blanked list and with getSingleResult you have an error (I'm sure is NoResultException) is probably because there is no records with email tomj@abc.com... Verify the camelCase in the record... Probably in the database is something like Tomj@abc.com or it has spaces or something like that